# zend framework (1.1) appending javascript files to footer?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there a out of the box way of loading certain javascripts in the footer of a view script?

This would be particularly useful for such scripts like google analytics, etc.

Or would this require extending $this->headScript() and creating a $this->footScript() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a [placeholder](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.placeholder) in your layout like `$this->layout()->footScript` and then attach the code you want to the [placeholder](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.placeholder).
 Or you could just use the inlineScript() Helper. The [inlineScript helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.inlinescript) has the same api is headScript(). 
The optimum would probably be to use the layout placeholder along with the inlineScript helper.

An Example of the [inlineScript helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.inlinescript):

```
//I use this in some of my controllers, in the predispatch()
$this->view->inlineScript()->setScript(
                "$('audio').mediaelementplayer();");

//then I just attach this to any view (including layout)
<?php echo $this->inlineScript() ?>
```

Use something like this with a placeholder and you have javascript anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP, putting `auto_append_file` in a `php.ini` file or `.htaccess` file may be what you are looking for.

Link: [php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file)

If you don't have access to `php.ini` you can put

```
php_value auto_append_file "file_to_append.php"
```

into an `.htaccess` file.

Keep in mind, however, that this will append it after the closing HTML tags, and therefore invalidate the markup.

I only use this for PHP scripts that don't output anything.